# C# SqlDataReader keeps reading

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a method for getting data out of my SQL Server database. I'm using a `reader` to get all the data. The problem is that the `reader` *keeps reading* and the application *doesn't pop up*. It is like an infinite loop or something.

```
public static List<Reservering> GetReserverings()
{
    Reservering res = new Reservering();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
            conn.Open();
            const string query = "select b.boekingid, k.naam, bk.incheckdatum, bk.uitcheckdatum, b.hotelid, b.aantal_gasten from boeking b join klant k on k.klantid = b.boekingid join boekingkamer bk on b.boekingid = bk.boekingid where bk.incheckdatum is not null and bk.uitcheckdatum is not null";

            SqlCommand selectReserveringen = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            SqlDataReader reader = selectReserveringen.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 res.Id =  (int)reader["boekingid"];
                 res.Naam = (string)reader["naam"];
                 res.Incheck_datum = (DateTime)reader["incheckdatum"];
                 res.Uitcheck_datum = (DateTime)reader["uitcheckdatum"];
                 res.Hotel = (int)reader["hotelid"];
                 res.Aantal_personen = (int)reader["aantal_gasten"];
            }

            reader.Close();
        }

        return GetReserverings();
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried executing the `SELECT` directly using SQL Server Management Studio? How many rows does it returned? It doesn't look like an "infinite" loop to me ...

Answer (score 5):

You've got an [infinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion) by calling the method itself at the end:

```
return GetReserverings();
```

You could've discovered this by setting a breakpoint in your method and stepping through your code.

You want to return a list of reservations instead:

```
var result = new List<Reservering>();

// your code...

return result;
```

And within your `while()` loop, you'd want to instantiate a new `Reservering` each iteration, and `Add` it to the result list.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an *instance* of `Reservering` for *each* record read and store these instances in the `List<Reservering>`:

```
public static List<Reservering> GetReserverings() {
  List<Reservering> result = new List<Reservering>();

  using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    conn.Open();

    const string query = 
      @"select b.boekingid, 
               k.naam, 
               bk.incheckdatum, 
               bk.uitcheckdatum, 
               b.hotelid, 
               b.aantal_gasten 
          from boeking b join 
               klant k on k.klantid = b.boekingid join 
               boekingkamer bk on b.boekingid = bk.boekingid 
         where bk.incheckdatum is not null 
           and bk.uitcheckdatum is not null";

     using (SqlCommand selectReserveringen = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
       using (SqlDataReader reader = selectReserveringen.ExecuteReader()) {
         while (reader.Read()) {
           Reservering res = new Reservering();
           result.Add(res); 

           res.Id              = Convert.ToInt32(reader["boekingid"]);
           res.Naam            = Convert.ToString(reader["naam"]);
           res.Incheck_datum   = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["incheckdatum"]);
           res.Uitcheck_datum  = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["uitcheckdatum"]);
           res.Hotel           = Convert.ToInt32(reader["hotelid"]);
           res.Aantal_personen = Convert.ToInt32(reader["aantal_gasten"]);  
         }
       } 
     }
   }      

   return result;
}
```

**Edit:** You can try to simplify `while` loop with a help of object initializing:

```
     ...
     while (reader.Read()) {
       result.Add(new Reservering() {
         Id              = Convert.ToInt32(reader["boekingid"]),
         Naam            = Convert.ToString(reader["naam"]),
         Incheck_datum   = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["incheckdatum"]),
         Uitcheck_datum  = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["uitcheckdatum"]),  
         Hotel           = Convert.ToInt32(reader["hotelid"]),
         Aantal_personen = Convert.ToInt32(reader["aantal_gasten"]) 
       });
     }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `result.Add(res);` be after you assign the values to is properties?

Comment: @Camadas: it can be either before or after: we create an instance, put it into collection and then assign properties, or create an instance, assign properties and then put it into the list.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static List<Reservering> GetReserverings()
    {
        List<Reserving> reservings = new List<Reservings>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
                conn.Open();
                const string query = "select b.boekingid, k.naam, bk.incheckdatum, bk.uitcheckdatum, b.hotelid, b.aantal_gasten from boeking b join klant k on k.klantid = b.boekingid join boekingkamer bk on b.boekingid = bk.boekingid where bk.incheckdatum is not null and bk.uitcheckdatum is not null";

                SqlCommand selectReserveringen = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                SqlDataReader reader = selectReserveringen.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                     Reservering res = new Reservering();
                     res.Id =  (int)reader["boekingid"];
                     res.Naam = (string)reader["naam"];
                     res.Incheck_datum = (DateTime)reader["incheckdatum"];
                     res.Uitcheck_datum = (DateTime)reader["uitcheckdatum"];
                     res.Hotel = (int)reader["hotelid"];
                     res.Aantal_personen = (int)reader["aantal_gasten"];
                     reservings.add(res);
                }

                reader.Close();
            }

            return reservings;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. Dumping "fixed" code doesn't teach the asker anything; and what you fixed is already pointed out by two other answers, with text. And if you think you need to fix your answer, then [edit] it instead of deleting and reposting it.